# wordpress multisite from exsiting 4 wordpress directory install

Tags: php, wordpress

I need help in changing multiple wordpress instances installed in distinct subdirectories into a single wordpress installation with multisite activation. Let me explain my problem briefly:

```
    example.com is my domain Hostgator shared hosting

   example.com/ - Homepage as index.php my own designed php file

   examole.com/university/ - wordpress 1st installation 
   example.com/school/ - wordpress 2nd installation 
   example.com/exam/ - wordpress 3rd installation
```

The reason why Idid this is I need different menus on each directory sites. I found no option t odo this in single wordpress.

Now I went through an article about wordpress multisite ; can I migrate all wordpress instances into a single wordpress with same folder having same site and contents ?

I currently have 200 posts on each wordpress and I don't want to lose the SERP results.

Is it possible to do without any effects and for all those sites ? I am the only admin.
Were I can have different menus and themes for each site on wordpress multisite ?

How to convert this in simple beginner level steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it , but before you need to get backup for the all websites, also import all your posts from all the wordpress installation

Create a Network in your main domain , for your reference [Create_Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)

Then create your child website, based on the

Sub-domains — a domain-based network in which on-demand sites use subdomains
Sub-directories — a path-based network in which on-demand sites use paths

so your child website should be like

```
   examole.com/university
   example.com/school 
   example.com/exam
```

Once you have successfully created your child websites then there would be a separate wp-admin for each child websites in your Main wp-admin, once you get logged in as admin ,

At the left of your WordPress toolbar, My Sites is now the second item. There, all your sites are listed, with handy fly-out menus, as well as a Network Admin menu item. Under Network Admin you can use the Dashboard item to go to the Network Dashboard screen.

then you can import your posts (already exported from your old websites) on each child webistes as possible ,

Hope this is enough to do it